# Update Query with Join and Where clause in joined table

Tags: join, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update one table joining another, found some links in the forum and referring to those only below is the query I have prepared:

```
update WO 
    set WO.[Status] = 'Closed'
from [Work Orders] as WO
WHERE 
    wO.[Seq.HD #] IN (
        select [Incident #] 
        from Incident INC 
        where 
            INC.[Category Description] = 'test'
        and INC.Network = 'test'
    )
    and WO.[Category Description] in('test1', 'test2')
```

Not sure why but it is updating all the records in `[Work Orders]` table.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well you may find that all the records in the [Work Orders] table match your where clause. If you do a 

select * FROM 
   [Work Orders] as WO
   where wO.[Seq.HD #] in(select [Incident #] from Incident INC 
   where  INC.[Category Description] = 'test'
  and INC.Network = 'test')
  and WO.[Category Description] in('test1',
'test2')

Do you get back what you expect?

Comment: Hi Cameron, Thanks for your reply. Yes when I fire Select statement I am getting what is required. but when I use the same condition and update the table all records are getting updated.

Comment: There's one more thing I have noticed, after update it shows a message that 7 rows are updated but there are more than 20000 rows matching above criteria and it is updating all the rows(more than 100000).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that those numbers are correct? By that I mean that it displays 7 rows, updates about 1,000,000 and that about 20,000 match? I doubt that this is really the case because that would point to a serious issue with SQL server.
How do you know that this SQL script is updating all of the rows? Could it be some other script that updating the rows?

Comment: Is this a production database, a local dev one or what?

Comment: This is the test database I am running script (which in sync with Prod database) and no one other than me is accessing this database. After running update script when I fire "Select * " it is showing all Status values as Closed

Comment: What were the values before you ran the script? Try setting them all to "Empty" and then run the script and see which are closed.

Comment: Tried setting al to null and then updated again but same result. Expected rows to get updated is 21629 but it is updating much more than this. Is this somewhere related to SQL Server version? I am using 2012

Comment: If there was a bug that caused more rows to be updated than expected that would be a major issue and it would have been found and patched in a hurry. I doubt that's the case. Can you script out a database create, table creates for the 2 tables and data insert scripts that reproduce so that I can see the issue in action? Otherwise I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Tauceef,

Try this query:
update WO 
    set WO.[Status] = 'Closed'
from [Work Orders] as WO
inner join 
(
        select [Incident #] 
        from Incident INC 
        where 
            INC.[Category Description] = 'test'
        and INC.Network = 'test'
    )a on wO.[Seq.HD #]= a.[Incident #]

WHERE 
WO.[Category Description] in('test1', 'test2')

Comment: Hi Sunny, tried your query but no luck :( same result as the one I have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your responses.

It was my mistake :( I was updating the views.

I have updated the query with tables and now it works fine.

Really sorry for the inconvenience.

Regards,
Tauceef